# How to enable pitch shifting in MPC?

Tags: audio, video, media-player, media-player-classic

How can I enable pitch shifting in MPC? I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_player_software) that Media Player Classic has pitch shifting but it seems it's not enabled (doesn't work?). I was wondering I have to do something to enable this feature, maybe I have to use some kind of custom decoder for audio?

**Note, by pitch shifting I mean something like YouTube where if you make the video faster, the audio also gets faster without losing its quality.**

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_player_software]

Comment: I've never seen MPC has such a feature. When I need that I've always had to use VLC

Comment: @phuclv here you go, scroll down and check the column for pitch shifting, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_player_software

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature was implemented in the [Time stretching](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/203#comment:29) ticket and applies to MPC's internal renderer. You can enable it by going to *Options > Playback > Output > Audio renderer* and choose **Internal Audio Renderer** (or **MPC Audio Renderer** in newer versions)

[image: Audio renderer settings]

[image: New audio renderer settings]

See [MPC-HC - How to increase/decrease video speed without changing the pitch of audio?](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/bebbyp/mpchc_how_to_increasedecrease_video_speed_without/)

Comment: This works!, of course the quality of the pitch shifting is clearly not as good as Youtube or other similar softwares, but it is still pitch shifting and the answer does satisfy my question, thanks.

Comment: going to Options > Playback > Output > Audio renderer and choose System default. then select resizer as Bicubic ... .  this way has better quality and also supports Realtek Audio Manager (or other sound card drivers app) app options.

Comment: "MPC Audio Renderer" was correct options in mine.

Comment: @ATES thanks. That was the name in MPC-BE and looks like the change made its way into MPC-HC